# Checking for walls existence in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

i am trying to make some agents behave if there is a wall between them , How i can check if there is a wall exists between agents in Anylogic  ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a simpler way, so this is what I do:
What I do, is to keep all my walls in a collection (arrayList)

Then I check if there's any wall between them (let's say person and person2 are your agents and wallsList is the list with all the walls in it)

```
Point q1=new Point(person1.getX(),person1.getY()); 
Point p1=new Point(person2.getX(),person2.getY()); 
for(Wall wall : wallsList){
    for(int i=0;i<wall.getSegmentCount();i++){
        Point p2=new Point(wall.getSegment(i).getStartX(),wall.getSegment(i).getStartY());
        Point q2=new Point(wall.getSegment(i).getEndX(),wall.getSegment(i).getEndY());
        if(doIntersect(p1, q1, p2, q2)){
            return true; // there is a wall
        }
    }
}
return false
```

Now what does the doIntersect function do:
well, I copied it from here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/